# How do I get around the color inversion that Gmail iOS does when the dark theme is active?

Tags: html, ios, email, gmail, darkmode

**My main task** is to write HTML/CSS code for an email that is designed with a dark background and light typography.

**The main problem** is that iOS Gmail does a complete color inversion if the dark theme is active.

Here's a snippet of the original design:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0X40.png)

Here's what it looks like in the dark iOS Gmail theme:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST6Me.png)

Here's what it looks like if I use the light design originally (light background, dark typography):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNssq.png)

**Question.** Is there any way around this behavior?

HTML code - [link](https://github.com/mynameistymur/awesomic-offer-email/blob/main/index.html)

Comment: Some code here???

Comment: Hi! I didn't share the code because there's no bug in the code here. The question here is whether there are ways to somehow bind to theme changes on the iOS Gmail device or to get around this iOS Gmail behavior.

Comment: But if it might help, I've added a link to GitHub.

https://github.com/mynameistymur/awesomic-offer-email/blob/main/index.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi! I am writing code for an existing email design. The design of this email is in dark colors, according to the brand identity. The problem is that Gmail on iOS devices displays the email with a full-color inversion if a dark theme is active, which either decreases readability and colors no longer match the brand identity. I want to find a way around this behavior of Gmail on iOS.